# How to replace elements in list when condition is met

Tags: python

Right now, I am struggling to find a proper answer. Let's say we have this list:

```
['12', '50', '12', '7', '7', '3', '4', '10', '19', '12']
```

As you can see, it's a list of strings. I *could* map this to a list of `ints`, but I won't, because I need to change them back to strings anyway. On the other hand, it would be handy if I would do it because I need to check for a condition.

**What do I need? -->** I need to change the elements in the list when a certain condition is met. So, for example: if a list in the element is greater than 10, I need to change the element to a certain character like a `plus (+)` or a `minus (-)`

Eventually, my list should be something like this:

```
['+', '+', '+', '-', '-', '-', '-', '+', '+', '+']
```

So, the concept in my head right now is:

- Don't convert the string to an int, because I will need to transform them to strings anyway *(hence the special characters I was talking about).*
- I need to use a `for loop`, because I want to check every element

I'd probably need to use a loop like this:

```
for score in scores:
   if score == "5": # check if element is a 5
      score == "+"  # make it a plus
   else:
      score == "-"  # make it a minus
```

**Problem:** this doesn't work and I don't even know if this is the right way. I can use `score[0]` and get every element in the list like this, but this wouldn't be efficient nor generic, or would it? What is the best way to transform elements in a list when a certain condition is met?

Can someone point in me the right direction please?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this (assuming you want 10 as the cutoff)

```
li = ['12', '50', '12', '7', '7', '3', '4', '10', '19', '12'] 

new_list = ['+' if int(el)>10 else '-' for el in li]
```

Comment: This assumes the OP doesn't need to make changes to the existing list.

Comment: not exactly newbie-friendly but that is the way to do it.

Comment: But this isn't generic? What would happen if my list would change? I don't like non-generic solutions, but thanks anyway!

Comment: What do you mean not generic?

Comment: @Siyah: Waht made you think it is not generic? Infact, it is the ideal way to achieve it

Comment: @Siyah What do you mean by that? the `new_list` definition takes whatever is in the `li` and works with that. Nothing is hard-coded here. And if you need to modify the list **in place** (not create an additional one that is) just change the `new_list` to `li`.

Comment: I think I got it, but... this assumes the elements in the list are ints, but they are not. So I should map them to an int first in that case?

Comment: @Siyah It does not. it does the conversion only for checking the condition. This is what makes it different from the solution posted by **Ganesh**.

Comment: Ahhhh! I see it now. Yes, damn. Foolish. Thanks man!

Comment: Can I ask a question btw? Can someone explain to me how the tranformation precisely happens? Because I don't understand where it changes it... because when I would write down this same loop on multiple lines (properly), I can't get it working. It just changes the whole list to a plus or a minus...

Comment: @Siyah, AFAIK looping through a list like `for score in scores:` and then trying to alter `score` inside the loop will not change the original list, `scores`

Comment: But isn't yours doing the same? You have a for loop... I don't get how it's transformed here...

Comment: No, mine is using [list comprehension](http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/list_comprehensions.hawk) which works by creating a new list (in memory) rather than altering the existing list. From there you can do whatever you want with it such as assign it to a new variable (like my example) or assign it to an existing variable.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work because:

1. A `for` loop in Python creates a new local variable, and
2. You used `==` instead of `=`.

Try this approach:

```
for index, score in enumerate(scores):
   if scores[index] == "5": # check if element is a 5
      scores[index] = "+"  # make it a plus
   else:
      scores[index] = "-"  # make it a minus
```

A quick side note: your question asks for "greater/smaller" then but your example uses `==`. If you want to test for greater or smaller you have to convert the elements to `int`.

Comment: `i` is not the same thing as `index`.  And what's the point of using `enumerate` if you aren't going to use the extracted values?

Comment: @ScottHunter thanks, fixed that

Comment: You don't use `score` so `enumerate` is not nedt. `for index in range(len(scores)):`

Comment: @Adirio Using `range(len(scores))` is considered to be less Pythonic.

Comment: @DeepSpace lol no, using a method only available in Python doens't mean you are more pythonic, your solution is less efficient in both time and resources

Comment: Thanks DeepSpace, I appreciate your help and upvoted. I do think that Leo's solution is more efficient though.

Comment: @Adirio Deespace is right in my opinion. What you see people do often when (as here) the item itself is not needed is something like `for index, _ in enumerate(scores):`. They use an underscore to show that this will not be used.

Comment: @Ev.Kounis The underscore usage as a "this won't be used" is actually quite pythonic, yes, same as enumerate and range methods. I would have to further inspect it but I think range is more resource-eficient in Python3 (range used to be a function returning a list while enumerate returned an iterator in Python2 but while enumerate behaviour has not changed range has, and now it returns a range object that only keeps start, end and step in memory https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq-range)

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

1. Initial `l = ['12', '50', '12', '7', '7', '3', '4', '10', '19', '12']`
2. Map to int: `l = list(map(int, l))`
3. Then: `a = ['+' if i>10 else '-' for i in l]`
4. a = `['+', '+', '+', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '+', '+']`

Comment: This assumes the OP doesn't need to make changes to the existing list.

Comment: You could actually do it in a single line `l = ['+' if i > 10 else '-' for i in map(int, l)]`

Comment: Ya kinda realized that by seeing the first post. Apparently 1 minute == 6 upvotes plus approved ;)